# show a div having style="display:none" after passing value to js variable

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Initially the div id =" showHide" is invisible. I want to make it visible when the value of **vall is not null**. But the code is not working. Though variable vall is getting values, the div is still not visible. What is the problem with js codescript?? I am using jsp.

```
<head>
</head>

<body>
<div id =" showHide" style="display:none">

    /*HTML TABLE*/
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

 alert("first alert");
 var vall = "<%=vall%>";    

    if (vall != null)
        {            
            var mydiv = getElementById.("showHide");
            mydiv.style.display ="block";
            alert("second alert");
            <% System.out.println("jsvar="+vall);%>

             }

    </script>
</body>
```

When I logged in the console i got the error:

> uncaught syntaxError: unexpected token (

and both the alert box are also not showing.

Comment: I have edited the code as per your suggestions but still it is not working.

Comment: That's because you changed your correct `document.getElementById("showHide");` to the incorrect `getElementById.("showHide");`. Change it back and the syntax error will go away.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
mydiv.style.display = "block";
```

instead of

```
mydiv.style.visibility = "visible";
```

Answer (score 2):

[`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/visibility) and [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display) are different. Instead you should change the `display` value from `none` to `block` (the default for a `<div>`):

```
mydiv.style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the content has actually been loaded before your JS is being called? Try moving your JS to the end of the body or wrap your code in a function that can be called on page load. If you want to be really fancy you should use jQuery to help you out with this. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id =" showHide" style="display:none"> 

/*HTML TABLE*/ 
</div>
```

remove the space of id and put the Js code to back of div , try it.

Comment: thanks for the correction. I've placed my js script after the closing div tag but also it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I think You forget to declare variable mydiv.

replace this line
 mydiv = document.getElementById("showHide");

by

var mydiv = document.getElementById("showHide");

```
enter code here<div id ="showHide" style="display:none">

/*HTML TABLE*/
```

// javascript code just check this out

```
var vall = 10;
var mydiv = null
if (vall != null)
    {
        mydiv = document.getElementById("showHide");
        mydiv.style.display ="block";

    }
```

Comment: thanks for the hawkeye. but it was only typo error. I corrected it though, still not working.

Comment: just do one thing where you declared vall variable at below side you declare mydiv variable like "var mydiv=null;"

Comment: hey remove space of id="ShowHide"

Answer (score 0):

I think when your code in the script tag runs it does not find the div tag with that id, and when the div is rendered in the page you again set its visibility to hidden.

I suggest to put your script tag after the div.

Comment: You can check if your if condition is true or not bye logging into console or putting an alert in it.

Comment: @ Digvijay Yadav: thanks for the suggestion. when I logged into the console i got the  error: "uncaught syntaxError: unexpected token ("

Comment: I got your error check the line saying getElementById().
Look for the misplaced dot(.). Also you have not used the document.getElementById('ShowHide');

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
 var mydiv = getElementById.("showHide");
```

use

```
 var mydiv = document.getElementById.("showHide");
```